# Expo start don't works after Upgrading Expo 26 to 32

Tags: react-native, expo

After upgrading `expo` from: SDK 26 to SDK 32, I have the following issue when I use `expo run emulator` or `expo app`:

> /Users/name user/project name/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js: Cannot read property ‘1’ of undefined

**AppEntry.js:**

```
import { KeepAwake, registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
import App from '../../App';


if (__DEV__) {
   KeepAwake.activate();
}

registerRootComponent(App);
```

**package.json:**

```
{
   “main”: “node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js”,
   “private”: true,
   “scripts”: {
      “test”: “node ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watchAll”
   },
   “jest”: {
       “preset”: “jest-expo”
   },
   “dependencies”: {
       “@expo/samples”: “2.1.1”,
       “babel-preset-expo”: “^5.1.1”,
       “expo”: “^32.0.0”,
       “npm”: “^4.6.1”,
       “react”: “16.5.0”,
       “react-native”: “https://github.com/expo/react- 
       native/archive/sdk- 32.0.0.tar.gz”,
       “react-native-animatable”: “^1.2.4”,
       “react-native-device-info”: “^0.21.5”,
       “react-native-drawer”: “^2.5.0”,
       “react-native-drawer-menu”: “^0.2.5”,
       “react-native-elements”: “^0.19.1”,
       “react-native-fetch-polyfill”: “^1.1.2”,
       “react-native-geocoder”: “^0.5.0”,
       “react-native-geocoding”: “^0.3.0”,
       “react-native-google-maps-directions”: “^2.0.0”,
       “react-native-keyboard-spacer”: “^0.4.1”,
       “react-native-maps”: “^0.21.0”,
       “react-native-masked-text”: “^1.6.5”,
       “react-native-qrcode-svg”: “^5.1.1”,
       “react-native-select-input-ios”: “^1.2.0”,
       “react-native-swipeable”: “^0.6.0”,
       “react-native-swiper”: “^1.5.13”,
       “react-native-touch-id”: “^4.0.4”,
       “react-native-vector-icons”: “^4.6.0”,
       “react-navigation”: “^3.0.9”
    },
    “devDependencies”: {
       “@babel/core”: “^7.4.3”,
       “@babel/preset-env”: “^7.0.0-beta.47”,
       “gulp-babel”: “^7.0.1”,
       “jest-expo”: “^32.0.0”
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
[After adjusting at the suggestion, I'm getting this error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHDCm.png)

> Users/user name/project name/App.js: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined

Any ideas on potential solutions to try? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the issue log for `expo`, I see someone else had a similar issue when updating from:

*SDK version 30 to SDK version 31*

and the issue was related to their `babel` configuration. Perhaps you're dealing with the same issue, maybe you could try the solution they [suggested](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2834) and see if that resolves your issue as well since you're updating from SDK version 26.

Here is what they suggested:

Install the latest version of `babel-plugin-module-resolver`:

```
npm i --save-dev babel-plugin-module-resolver@latest
```

alternatively:

```
yarn add babel-plugin-module-resolver@latest
```

Additionally, others had to change their `.babelrc` contents to use the `"babel-preset-expo"` preset:

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["babel-preset-expo"]
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Your response is great.
I had seen this comment but it looks like I had updated it in a wrong way. Now I'm getting this error:

**App.js: Can not read property 'filename' of undefined**

When searching I found many answer that it was necessary to change the .babelrc file, but I can not find it and I do not know where I created it and there is need.

Comment: Thanks, can you add the full stack trace so I can make heads and tails of it?

Comment: I do not understand, but see if that's what you want, I'll edit the question with more information.

Comment: Sorry, I just want to see the full message related to this error message:  App.js: Can not read property 'filename' of undefined. This way I can try to understand what's going on better

Comment: thanks, seems to be babel config issue? If you don't have a .babelrc file within your root directory can you add one with the following contents: {"presets": ["babel-preset-expo"]} ? By root directory I mean the base where your package.json and other important files are defined. See https://github.com/tidepool-org/mobile/tree/6a77cf5b96089b158a62cde979f3a9e0fdc2726d for an example of what I mean. I might try using his babel.config.js file too if that doesnt work

Comment: After hours and hours it seems like I did not know a basic question, I did not know that the documents with dot before the name were hidden! After discovering such an event and unpacking the folders, I was able to change the .babelrc and fix it with your tip. Now it is giving error in other components, but now I turn. Thank you!

Comment: @ThalesCrisostomo I am glad you figured it out! I added my comment to the answer since it helped you out. Please accept my answer :)